# In remote host: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

Tags: email, symfony1, smtp, gmail

after deploying I gettin this error below when i try to send an mail:

500 | Internal Server Error | Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
stack trace

```
* at ()
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php line 235 ...
         232.     }
         233.     if (!$this->_stream = fsockopen($host, $this->_params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout))
         234.     {
         235.       throw new Swift_TransportException(
         236.         'Connection could not be established with host ' . $this->_params['host'] .
         237.         ' [' . $errstr . ' #' . $errno . ']'
         238.         );
* at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection()
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php line 70 ...
          67.         break;
          68.       case self::TYPE_SOCKET:
          69.       default:
          70.         $this->_establishSocketConnection();
          71.         break;
          72.     }
          73.   }
* at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(array('protocol' => 'ssl', 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 'port' => 465, 'timeout' => 30, 'blocking' => 1, 'type' => 1))
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 101 ...
          98.       
          99.       try
         100.       {
         101.         $this->_buffer->initialize($this->_getBufferParams());
         102.       }
         103.       catch (Swift_TransportException $e)
         104.       {
* at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Mailer.php line 74 ...
          71.     
          72.     if (!$this->_transport->isStarted())
          73.     {
          74.       $this->_transport->start();
          75.     }
          76.     
          77.     return $this->_transport->send($message, $failedRecipients);
* at Swift_Mailer->send(object('Swift_Message'), array())
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/mailer/sfMailer.class.php line 300 ...
         297.       return $this->realtimeTransport->send($message, $failedRecipients);
         298.     }
         299.
         300.     return parent::send($message, $failedRecipients);
         301.   }
         302.
         303.   /**
* at sfMailer->send(object('Swift_Message'))
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/mailer/sfMailer.class.php line 263 ...
         260.    */
         261.   public function composeAndSend($from, $to, $subject, $body)
         262.   {
         263.     return $this->send($this->compose($from, $to, $subject, $body));
         264.   }
         265.
         266.   /**
* at sfMailer->composeAndSend('tirengar@gmail.com', 'tirengarfio@hotmail.com', 'Confirm Registration', 'Hello fjklsdjf,<br/><br/> <a href="http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs5/web/frontend_dev.php/register/confirm/m/19">Click here to confirm your registration</a><br/><br/> Your login information can be found below:<br/><br/> Username: fjklsdjf<br/> Password: m')
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardExtraPlugin/modules/sfGuardRegister/lib/BasesfGuardRegisterActions.class.php line 89 ...
          86.       $user->getEmailAddress(),
          87.       'Confirm Registration',
          88.       $message
          89.     );
          90.   }
          91.
          92.   /**
* at BasesfGuardRegisterActions->sendRegisterConfirmMail(object('sfGuardUser'), 'm')
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardExtraPlugin/modules/sfGuardRegister/lib/BasesfGuard
```

This is my configuration in factories.yml.

```
all:
  mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: realtime
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        param:
          host:       smtp.gmail.com
          port:       465
          encryption: ssl
          username:   tirengarfio
          password:   XXXX
```

The port 465 is open the my remote host. No problem in localhost.

Any idea?

-- 
Javi

Ubuntu 8.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have taken these instructions directly from gmail site.

you have to use @gmail.com in your username.

```
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - requires TLS: smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)
Use Authentication: Yes
Use STARTTLS: Yes (some clients call this SSL)
Port: 465 or 587
Account Name:   your full email address (including @gmail.com) 
Google Apps users, please enter username@your_domain.com
Password:   your Gmail password
```

Comment: Can you do the following on the server?
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465

also why did you ding me -1?  I gave a valid answer.

Comment: Hi @ChrisMuench, I'm using Laravel 5.1 and getting a similar issue.  I've followed your outline in my .env file, can you verify?  drive=smtp, host=smtp.gmail.com, port=587 (also tried 465), encryption=ssl (also tried tls), username=me@gmail.com, password=secret, sendmail=/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs.  This currently doesn't work and produces: Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

You need to open 465 on firewall

On CSF firewall you need to add 465 on TCP_OUT =

Comment: Can you should us how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, buy I've run with the same problem on my local machine (Windows). For resolving this I had to copy two dlls on the php directory to system32(ssleay.dll and libeay.dll) and unncoment the extension php_openssl.dll on my apache configuration. There might be a similar solution for linux. I suggest you contact the hosting because it's quite possible that you cannot perform this solution on a shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem for a while, replacing: `smtp.gmail.com` with `173.194.65.108` actually worked for me!

Comment: Got error right the away `Connection could not be established with host 173.194.65.108 [ #0]`

Answer (score -1):

If you get this constantly without any luck, then check the settings again.
I was overlooking my settings and later found the host was wrong.

I used,
`smtp.google.com`

instead of
`smtp.gmail.com`

Too silly, but it happened to me.