# What is the best way to sent out email in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a problem sending out email in my Laravel 5 Application.

---

Here is my mail function

email = `test@gmail.com`

```
Mail::send('emails.activation', array(

  'username'=>$user->username,
  'name'=>$user->name,
  'code'=>$user->code,
  'email'=>$user->email

  ),
function($message){
  $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'),'Site');
  $message->to('email', 'name' )->subject('Site Activation ');
});
```

---

I keep getting

[image]

---

## Update

Mail Configuration in `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=donotreply@site.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***********
```

---

New Error

[image]

---

I'm very curios on what is going on.
What did I do wrong ?

Comment: What does RFC 2822, 3.6.2 state?

Comment: does not comply ? what is that even mean ? My email is valid.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.2

Comment: there is something wrong in email address fields such as From, Sender or Reply-To fields. Swift Mailer strictly follow RFC standard to avoid emails being caught by spam checker tools.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, but what's wrong with my `test@gmail.com` ?

Comment: looks like a spam because am not sure gmail would allow u to have test@gmail.com, also you didn't speify and email for 'to' as in  `$message->to('email', 'name' )->subject('Site Activation ');` replace 'email' with real email if you are not doing so

Comment: The 'from' address is perhaps not valid - did you try changing the `env` call to a real email address for testing purposes?

Comment: @SaeX : I haven't. I'll do it now. : )

Comment: @Digitlimit : I'm afraid that I can't do that because that suppose to me the email of my registered user, I have to email them the activation link, so that email must be their email.

Comment: in that case you can handle the exception `Swift_RfcComplianceException` with an exception handler, however its the duty of your application to reject invalid email

Comment: I'm new to this Laravel 5 Framework. Do you have any suggestion on where I can start to handle that ? Thanks man..

Comment: I will quickly write one for you

Comment: MAIL_USERNAME=donotreply@site.com should be your gmail email address

Comment: It's legit. It's gmail, and It's `donotreply@aveniros.com`. I just don't want to expose that in the post.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731788/in-remote-host-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-co

Comment: I really appreciate your help bud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means there is something wrong in email address fields such as From, Sender or Reply-To fields.

Swift Mailer strictly follow RFC standard to avoid emails being caught by spam checker tools.

`test@gmail.com` doesn't look like a normal email address or does not even exist.

Try with a different email address example send to me

```
Mail::send('emails.activation', array(

  'username'=>$user->username,
  'name'=>$user->name,
  'code'=>$user->code,
  'email'=>$user->email

  ),
function($message){
  $message->from('siteEmailaddress@domain.com'),'Site');
  $message->to('avalidEmailaddress@domain.com', 'name' )->subject('Site Activation ');

});
```

Also if you wish to use gmail as SMTP server below:

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 465,
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => 'your-email@gmail.com',
'password' => 'your-password',
```

EDITED

NB: `MAIL_USERNAME` must be your `@gmail.com` email address e.g. myname@gmail.com else you will get Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com error

To handle this exception if you can't resolve it, go to open app\Exceptions\handler.php

add this inside render method:

```
    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {


        if ($e instanceof Swift_RfcComplianceException){
            //redirect to form
            //You can also delete the user account here if already created or do other stuffs
            return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('error',"We have issue sending you an email");

        }


        .......
        
    }
```

NB: Remember to add `use Swift_RfcComplianceException;` at the top of handler.php

Comment: Your SMTP configuration is **exactly** what I have.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, but I still get the **timeout** error message. I'm very curious ????

Comment: When I set `MAIL_USERNAME=my-email@gmail.com` with the `gmail` as part of it. It works. I just want to give you an update on that. Maybe you can include that as part of you answer and **bold** it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the 'from' address is not valid, you're using an `env` call currently without knowing 100% what it returns.

Try changing the `from` address to a real email address for testing purposes.

Comment: After changing to a real email - I got this error `Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Operation timed out #60]`

Comment: OK, one step further ;-). Your SMTP server settings seem to be incorrect though. If you want to use the gmail SMTP server, you'll need to provide a username and password. Try using the SMTP server of e.g. your service provider (which usually doesn't require authentication).

Comment: I did. I provide/configure everything in my `.env` file.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how I can fix that timeout error message ?